# Nearest Neighbor using Voronoi Diagram

Tags: nearest-neighbor, voronoi

I have a question regarding Voronoi Diagram structure. why Voronoi Diagram is efficient for nearest neighbor search? How it works? i know that this structure is partitioning the space into cells but i still could not understand how it works when the search query is performed.

Comment: Better to ask at cstheory.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

You need a data structure like a hierarchical cluster or a spatial index.  The kirkpatrick algorithm seems very close but you can try a combination of a metric tree and a voronoi diagram:http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~phlosoft/voronoi/. The voronoi diagram is also good for pathfinding:http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~pblaer/projects/path_planner/ because it's the dual of the delaunay triangulation and the minimum spanning tree. Of course you can check each cell but it's trivial and a good exercise for the reader.